# How do I "refresh" element in DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

I've got an empty DIV element in which I append images by using  function createElement("img") and append them with appendChild. So now I've got DIV element full of images.

I would like to use one button to clean this DIV and add new images in it simultaneously. 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you just looking for method `replaceChild? Or you could remove all child elements before adding new images:`

```
// assuming yor div is in variable divelement
while (divelement.firstChild)
  divelement.removeChild(divelement.firstChild);
```

Answer (score 3):

what do you mean by clean? If you just want to empty it, you can do

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = '';
```

And then add on whatever new images you want.

Answer (score 3):

While both setting innerHTML and calling removeChild() in a loop will clear the contents out of the DIV, the innerHTML method is going to be much faster due to the nature of browsers today.